# What is the notation for a full set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

The empty set is $\{\}$, but is there a convenient notation for the full set given that the current universe of elements is implicit? Can I use this: $\{ \ldots \}$ ?

Comment: The "full set" ? "There is no standard notation for the [universal set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_set#Notation) of a given set theory. Common symbols include $V, U$".

Comment: If your universe is the set $U$, the notation for it is $U$.

Comment: The standard notation for the empty set is possible because there is just one empty set. A "full set" depends on context, so it's best to give it a name in that context.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I have a set datastructure in a Java program, and I want to create a set that always returns true if you ask it if any element belongs to the set. So I was thinking about how to print a representation of the set. Printing $V$ or $U$ would be confusing.

Comment: Every element belongs to the "universal set" and so every element does not belong to the empty set. Thus, you can test for an element $a$ whatever  if $a \notin \emptyset$ and the result will always be TRUE.

Comment: If your universe is implicit then so is complementation.  I suppose you could call if $\emptyset^c$ if you didn't have any other symbol for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little unclear if what you want is $U$ or $\mathcal P(U)$ (if your universe is the set $U$).

Comment: I guess this is the correct answer to my question, even though it was not really what I was looking for.